# IOS App Action extension is not closing

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I am facing app extension close issues , please tell me if anyone know what wrong am doing.I am using action extension after preform some action inside extension i need to return response back.

Sample Code

```
// With Success Case
- (void) completeActionWithItems: (NSString *) response {
    NSExtensionItem *extensionItem = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];
    extensionItem.attachments = @[[[NSItemProvider alloc] response typeIdentifier: (NSString *)kUTTypePlainText]];
   [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems: @[extensionItem] completionHandler: nil];
}


// With Error Case
- (void) completeActionWithError: (NSError *) error {
     [self.extensionContext cancelRequestWithError: error];
}
```

With Success Case working fine but some time is not closing,
With Error Case not working above code.
Please let me know what went wrong.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you create an action extension, this is the default method which will close the Action Extension View Controller:

```
- (IBAction)done {
// Return any edited content to the host app.
// This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed in items.

[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:self.extensionContext.inputItems completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Since this method is already provided, you should just try calling it from your success method.

```
// With Success Case
- (void) completeActionWithItems: (NSString *) response {
NSExtensionItem *extensionItem = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];
extensionItem.attachments = @[[[NSItemProvider alloc] response typeIdentifier: (NSString *)kUTTypePlainText]];
   [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems: @[extensionItem] completionHandler: nil];

// Call to "done" method
[self done];
}
```